# Where can i donwload xhci_hcd kernel driver?

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel

I accidently deleted the kernel driver related to my hub (docking station): xhci_hcd.

```
[ 2543.191957] usb usb2-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Where can I find it?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I accidentally deleted xhci_hcd driver after trying to install realtek usb network driver.

I found out about it When I connected the Hub and it didn't recognized by the OS, so using `dmesg` command, I got the output:
`[ 2543.191957] usb usb2-port2: unable to enumerate USB device.`

So I looked for usb2 in lshw and got the output:

```
*-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: Tiger Lake-LP USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 20
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:163 memory:603f260000-603f26ffff
```

Under the `configuration` section I saw that the driver needed for the hub is xhci_hcd.

If something is wrong in my research and conclusions, I would be happy to hear.

If the problem is really this missing driver/module, how and where can I get it from?

Is it part of a package?

Comment: "deleted the kernel driver" how?

Comment: You've provided no actual OS/release details; and if using a Ubuntu system (esp. LTS) there are more than a single kernel stack option thus *kernel modules* (aka *drivers*) can actually differ.  If you want to find the code, all are located on launchpad.net (or further upstream too), but we can't be specific as you've provided no OS/release & kernel stack option (*the kernel stack default is set by ISO used to install your system which we don't know*).

Comment: @Rinzwind I commented the way it happened.
What additional information can I provide ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe here:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/log/?qt=grep&q=usb

But I think Ubuntu should get the firmware automatically.

What kind of docking station do you have?

Comment: I bought this one: 

https://www.amazon.com/-/he/dp/B0BQ65KG3V/ref=sr_1_8?keywords=%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA+%D7%A2%D7%92%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%94+%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%91+%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%93&s=pc&sr=1-8

The LAN was configured to 100Mbit instead of 1Gbit, so I assumed the problem is with a driver. Downloaded Realtek driver named: r8152-2.17.1 and durring the installation it provided some errors and stucked. After that I realized that this module probably deleted the current one, which was the xhci_hcd.

Comment: I cannot open the link.

Comment: maybe search the driver on the Vendor homepage?